# How would I be able to add an Edit to the table at the end of the table

Tags: php, html, search, html-table, edit

How would I be able to add an Edit to the table after the table. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried a number of variations such as : Trying to add   Edit

```
      <center><?php
     //connect to mysql for search
     if(isset($_POST['search']))
     {
     $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
     // search in all table columns
     // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `2016server` WHERE CONCAT(`ServerGroup`,  
    `Week`,  `Status`, `ServerName`, `IP`, `DateComplete`, `DateSched`, 
    `HeatTicket`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
     $search_result = filterTable($query);

     }
     else {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `2016server`";
     $search_result = filterTable($query);
     }

     // function to connect and execute the query
      function filterTable($query)
      {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "");
   $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
    }

    ?>
   //start the webpage
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>SEARCH 2016 Servers</title>

   </head>
   <body>

    <center><h3>Type in your query to search all of the 2016 
    Servers</h3><br>

    <form action="search2016.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="SEARCH">
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="GO!"><br><br>
        table
        <table>

            <tr>
                <th>ServerGroup</th>
              <th>Server Name</th>
                  <th>Date Scheduled</th>
                 <th>Heat Ticket</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Date Complete</th>
                <th>Week</th>
                <th>Downtime</th>
                <th>IP Address</th>
                 <th>Operating System</th>


            </tr>

         populate table from mysql database 

            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $row['ServerGroup'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ServerName'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['DateSched'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['HeatTicket'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Status'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['DateComplete'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Week'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['DT'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['IP'];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['os'];?></td>
```

This is the section that I'm trying to add the edit to in the table. From the edit code above, it's trying to go to the 2016edit.php page with the ID how ever since there is no such page, it gets a 404 error.

```
        </tr>

      <?php endwhile;?>
    </table>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uh.......what? Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a table that I'm trying to edit. After clicking on the edit link, it goes to a php page that you can update the information and then submit it to the server.

Comment: If you want to have an extra page for the editing, why don't just use a form?

Comment: I have a table for the user to see... I'm trying to get an edit link on every row that goes to another page for editing.

Answer (score 1):

1. close the first `<form` tag early (after the `<input type="submit"`)
2. add new column named action where you'll put your edit button
3. use this for the edit

   `<form action="youreditform.php" method="post">
       <button type="submit" name="edit" value="<?= $theidofthis; ?>">Edit</button>
    </form>`

Comment: I see what you are trying to say. I was able to get the Edits in the rows, but when I put $ServerName, instead of the $theIDof this, I'm getting an error.

Comment: I don't know what is inside `$serverName` variable and what error did you get, but it supposed to be an id of the item in this row which you want to edit. So if the form is being submit, youreditform.php will get the id with variable name edit `$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'edit');`

Answer (score 0):

Add another "td" tag and make it a link and it will go to the next edit page on click. but for editing purpose you have to post id in the url to check that which record was clicked to edit. hope it will be helpful.

```
           <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['ServerGroup'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ServerName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['DateSched'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['HeatTicket'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Status'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['DateComplete'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Week'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['DT'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['IP'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['os'];?></td>
            <td><a href='edit.php'>edit</a></td>

        </tr>
```

Comment: No, that does not point to the particular ID that I need it to. It has to go to the record on which the line it is associated with.

Comment: For that purpose you have to post id in url to point the particular record. its easy

Comment: I did the same thing using this technique

Comment: I think I'm on the right track, but It's not working properly.. <th><form action="2016edit.php=$row['ID']" method="post">

Comment: No this is wrong. Your script will not work. Look you just have to send id in url while redirecting and on the other page you will check that which id was posted. if you are not able to do it then tell me.

Comment: @DustinVicent,    
You can use the following script to send id in url
echo "<td> <a href='edit.php?link={$row['id']}'>edit</a> </td>";
you can get this id on the other page in avariable using following script
$get_id = $_GET['link']; 
now you will update the record in database against this id. hope it will be helpful